# como eliminar texto de un archivo html con java

Tags: java

estoy tratando de eliminar una parte del texto de un archivo html (el archivo es una pagina descaragda.
 Necesito indicarle el punto donde comience a borrar y de ahi hasta el final. hay alguna forma de indicarle en que palabra comenzar o la ubicacion segun el numero de byte o linea? que se utilizaria? 
Gracias, saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un java.io.RandomAccessFile.

Con esta clase puedes leer del archivo y también escribir para modificarlo o extenderlo.

Con el método setLength(long len) puedes truncar el archivo al tamaño que quieras borrando el resto o también puedes extenderlo.

Te pongo un ejemplo pero no es para que lo uses sino para que veas como funciona y leas más de la clase.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

```
truncaArchivoDespuesDe("<body>");



public void truncaArchivoDespuesDe(String etiqueta) throws IOException {
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("ArchivoDescargado.html","rw");
    String linea = raf.readLine();
    while (linea != null) {
       if (linea.equals(etiqueta)) {
           raf.setLength(raf.getFilePointer()); //aqui truncamos el archivo a su 
                  // nuevo tamaño que será el de la posición
                  // actual (en el siguiente renglón de la etiqueta encontrada)
           return;
       }
       linea = raf.readLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracuas @AlbertoLopez, funciona muy bien y es lo que necesitaba. Una consulta, el metodo me borra desde la linea siguiente hasta el final, hay alguna forma de hacer que no borre hasta el final? por ejemplo indicando un limite con una linea? Gracias otra vez, sigo leyendo sobre la clase. Saludos

Comment: Creo que no @victorleroz, para lo que necesitas quizás lo más conveniente es crear otro archivo con otro RandomAccessFile, uno de entrada el cual vas a leer, y otro el de salida, en el que vas a escribir.Una vez que acabes puedes borrar el archivo de entrada, y hacer un "rename" para cambiar el nombre del nuevo por el anterior. ¿entiendes?